# I am trying to toggle my Boolean by IsFormDisplayed function

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, boolean, toggle

Hey I am calling the IsFormDisplayed function from . I want this function to toggle between true and false every time I call it. Can you tell what am I doing wrong?

I have tried it by creating if else function. But it stays the same.

my function is like this..this give me false value every time

````
            let FormCondition = true;
            FormCondition = !FormCondition;
            console.log(FormCondition);
              },```          

no error massage[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE9oQ.png
````

Comment: of course it will give you the same value. every time you call the function you declare it again and reverting the value. you need to declare it once and use it after then. like using global variable or so.

Comment: dude thank you I solved it...I never thought about it..tnxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 let formCondition = true;

 function toggle() {
   formCondition = !formCondition
   console.log(formCondition)
 }

 toggle()
 toggle()
```